# pyodbc executemany on merge statement with returning values

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2014, pyodbc

I am using MS SQL Server 2014. I have following code:

```
import pyodbc, time
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=192.xxx.xxx.xxx;DATABASE=test;UID=xx;PWD=xxxxx')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# cursor.fast_executemany = True
values = [(x,  "one_{0}".format(x), "ONE_{0}".format(x), 100) for x in range(300000)]

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE employees
( id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  salary MONEY
);
""")
cursor.commit()

t1 = time.time()

cursor.executemany("""
MERGE employees USING ( 
VALUES 
    (?, ?, ?, ?)
) AS vals (id, last_name, first_name, salary)
ON employees.id = vals.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    last_name = vals.last_name,
    first_name = vals.first_name,
    salary = vals.salary
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, last_name, first_name, salary)
    VALUES (vals.id, vals.last_name, vals.first_name, vals.salary)
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.last_name, inserted.first_name, inserted.salary;
""", values )
cursor.commit()

t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

Here, if measure the performance of above snippet without enabling `fast_executemany`, it will take 35-40 seconds. And if I enable the `fast_executemany` with, then it will take just 500 milliseconds.

if I tried to fetch the results as `cursor.fetchmany()` or `cursor.fetchall()`; it gives an error as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d84781edf8ac> in <module>()
----> 1 cursor.fetchmany()

ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

I want the returning values of above upsert behaviour. In my above snippet, I have used 300000 samples. That is my normal scenario.

Is it possible with MSSQL Server 2014 and pyodbc driver? any other way to achieve the desired result in MSSQL Server?

Comment: @Parfait Just updated my post. It gives an error.

Comment: i have just checked the database. It has inserted around 300 records. and if i execute again then another 280-300 records will be inserted. This is weird. I was in impression that it is inserting all of them.

Comment: again, i ran the merge statement; it randomly insert or not insert. Sometime just 1-2 documents and sometimes no insert at all. Now the count is 862 after running merge statement for 12-15 times. Sometimes it increases, and sometimes don't. count should reach 300000. It looks like a bug.

Comment: Is your question regarding obtaining returned values or undesired `MERGE` results? And without data we cannot possibly help. Try a few rows of data that mirror your actual, and test your merge action. Post the input/output data for us to see. You've been around SO a bit to know about [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You might have better luck by using `fast_executemany` to upload the rows to a global temporary table (ref: [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/295)) and then MERGE the rows from the temporary table to the main table *en masse*.